# Unit testing- $state.includes error is blocking other tests /how to mock state

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test the init function of this controller.I cannot find a way of doing this and keep getting the error

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$state.includes('profile.details')')

My main concern is to mock the state so that this error goes away and my other tests can pass and then I will focus on writing the test for the init statement. I have tried mocking the state as a string and using transitionTo, has anyone else found a way of testing includes for states?

```
var init = function () {
            $scope.global = global;
            $scope.partialViews = {
                personForm: "/app/users/views/details/_personForm.html",
                passwordForm: "/app/users/views/details/_passwordForm.html"
            };

            if (!$state.includes('profile.details') && !$state.includes('profile.organizations')) {
                if (global.activeProfile.defaultOrganizationId) {
                    $state.go("dashboard.notifications", { orgId: global.activeProfile.defaultOrganizationId });
                } else {
                    $state.go("profile.organizations");
                }
            }
        };
```

As an aside I went back to reading the docs to see how the .includes method works in hopes that it would help me figure out what I am doing wrong in my unit tests. in the MDN docs the .includes example is [1, 2, 3].includes(2); but typing this into the console responded with a

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

why is that?

my tests:

```
beforeEach(module('pb.users.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

    var mockUserService = {};
    var mockOrganizationService = {};
    var mockPersonInvitationService = {};
    var mockStateParams = {};
    var mockState = "profile.details";
    var mockGlobal = {};
    var mockForm = {};
    var mockModal = {};
    var invitation = {};

    beforeEach(inject(function ($q) {
        invitation = {
            organizationId: 6542643
        };
        mockForm = {
            submitIfValid: function (promiseHandler) {
                return promiseHandler();
            }
        };
        mockStateParams = {
            accountId: 7672891,
            entityId: 532,
            orgId: 67,
            page: 43,
            length: 12
        };
        mockGlobal = {
            setFormSubmitInProgress: function (boolean) {
                this.formProgress = boolean;
            },
            formProgress: false,
            activeOrganizationId: 432,
            organizationsUpdated: function () {
                return "updated!"
            }
        };
        mockUserService = {
            user: {
                person: {
                    name: 'Regan Perkins'
                }
            },
            getUser: function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(this.user);
                return defer.promise;
            },
            updateExtendedInfo: function (person) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(this.user);
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };

        mockOrganizationService = {
            organizations: {
                groups: ["PressBoard", "MySite"]
            },
            getOrganizations: function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(this.organizations);
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };
        mockPersonInvitationService = {
            invitations: ["invite one", "invite two"],
            getInvitations: function () {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(this.invitations);
                return defer.promise;
            },
            acceptInvitation: function (organizationId) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(invitation);
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };

    }));


    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
        controller = $controller('ProfilesController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $stateParams: mockStateParams,
            $state: mockState,
            $modal: mockModal,
            global: mockGlobal,
            userService: mockUserService,
            organizationService: mockOrganizationService,
            personInvitationService: mockPersonInvitationService
        });
    }));

    describe('init() function', function () {
        it('should set activeOrganizationId', function () {
            expect(scope.global.activeOrganizationId).toEqual(mockGlobal.activeOrganizationId);
        });

        it('should set global', function () {
            expect(scope.global).toEqual(mockGlobal);
        });

    });

    describe('get() function', function () {

        it('should resolve a promise', function () {
            scope.get();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.person).toEqual(mockUserService.user.person);
        });

    });

    describe("edit() function", function () {

        it("should toggle personFormSuccess", function () {
            spyOn(mockUserService, "updateExtendedInfo").and.callThrough();
            scope.edit(mockForm, mockUserService.user);
            expect(mockUserService.updateExtendedInfo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockUserService.user);
        });

        it("should call updateExtendedInfo()", function () {
            spyOn(mockUserService, "updateExtendedInfo").and.callThrough();
            scope.edit(mockForm, mockUserService.user);
            expect(scope.personFormSuccess).toBe(false);
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.personFormSuccess).toBe(true);
        });

    });

    describe('getOrganizations() function', function () {

        it('should resolve a promise', function () {
            scope.getOrganizations();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.organizations).toEqual(mockOrganizationService.organizations);
        });

    });

    describe('getInvitations() function', function () {

        it('should resolve a promise', function () {
            scope.getInvitations();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.invitations).toEqual(mockPersonInvitationService.invitations);
        });

    });

    describe('acceptInvitation() function', function () {

        it('should toggle form progress', function () {
            scope.invitations = mockPersonInvitationService.invitations;
            scope.acceptInvitation(invitation, 1);
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.invitations).toEqual(mockPersonInvitationService.invitations);
        });

        it('should resolve a promise', function () {
            scope.invitations = mockPersonInvitationService.invitations;
            scope.acceptInvitation(invitation, 1);
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.invitations).toEqual(mockPersonInvitationService.invitations);
        });

        it('should resolve a promise', function () {
            scope.invitations = mockPersonInvitationService.invitations;
            scope.acceptInvitation(invitation, 1);
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.invitations).toEqual(['invite one']);
        });

    });

    describe("openRejectInvitation() function", function () {
        var actualOptions;
        var modalOptions = {
            templateUrl: '/app/users/views/organizations/_removeInvite.html',
            controller: 'RejectInvitationModalController',
            resolve: {
                invitation: function () {
                    return invitation;
                }
            }
        };

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $q) {
            mockModal.open = function (options) {
                actualOptions = options;
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve();
                return { result: defer.promise };
            }
        }));

        it("make sure modalInstance.result.then is executed", function () {
            scope.invitations = mockPersonInvitationService.invitations;
            scope.openRejectInvitation(invitation, 1);
            expect(scope.invitations).toEqual(['invite one', 'invite two']);
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.invitations).toEqual(['invite one']);
        });

        it("make sure modal.open is called", function () {
            spyOn(mockModal, 'open').and.callThrough();
            scope.openRejectInvitation(invitation, 1);
            expect(mockModal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(actualOptions);
        });

        it("make sure 'webSite' is passed by modalInstance.resolve", function () {
            scope.openRejectInvitation(invitation, 1);
            expect(actualOptions.resolve.invitation()).toEqual(invitation);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you please provide your unit test code? There is mock for $state https://gist.github.com/wilsonwc/8358542

Comment: Kostya Shkryob thanks for the comment I added my code and changed the question a around a little bit. I have tried using the mock $state you linked to but with no luck.

Comment: Now I see that the mock I have suggested doesn't have includes function. Regarding array.includes method MDN says it's experimental and supported only in FF nightly builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase this helps anyone else with this problem the way I was able to bypass this error was to mock the includes method on my mockState.

```
var mockState = {
        includes: function (string) {
            return false
        }
};
```